# Is there a separate site to ask questions about God?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I saw religious SE sites like Hinduism, Christianity, Islam, etc. But over all we can say **God** regardless of religious. I want to ask a question about God, but not specific to a religion. Is there a separate SE available?

Note: My question will be 'If God exist then why do people, who didn't do any crime or sin (particularly children or new born baby), get deadly diseases?

The pain they are getting is their own pain that God is not feeling instead of them.'

If I want to ask this question, what is the best suitable site to ask and I don't mind if it will be closed as off topic.

Note: I can ask this question on Hinduism as I'm based in that religion, but I want a *generic* answer.

Comment: The concept of "Karma" is specific to a religion (Hinduism/Buddhism)... so I'm not really sure why you think this question is without religious bent. I'm also not exactly sure how you expect anyone to answer the question "why do bad things happen to innocent people" in a way that's in any way meaningful.

Comment: If Karma is related to Hinduism/Buddhism then I will remove it from my question.

Comment: @Catija Yes! I understand that this is hard to answer. But I want a Source to understand the concept behind this. If anyone answering or sharing a comment regarding this topic(regardless of religion) It would be good.

Comment: Well, it's easy for me... there's no such thing as "god", so it's just that crappy stuff happens to everyone. I don't really understand the question... the need to attribute reason to a child getting sick or dying. It just sucks and it happens and that's it.

Comment: @Catija. That's Fine. me too the same category :-P

Answer (score 11, accepted):

People mean different things when they talk about God, so it's hard to ask a question without reference to *some* religion.  You might be able to ask a question about this on [Philosophy](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com); they have a "god" tag.

Your question as you've outlined it here might be closed as either too broad or primarily opinion-based.  Your question sounds like a *topic for discussion* more than an *answerable question*.  Theodicy is a huge topic with many possible answers.  Instead, consider asking *according to somebody* -- what does such-and-such theology/philosopher teach about this?

Be sure to read the tour and "what is on-topic" Help Center post on any site before asking this question.  Doing so will help you learn what a site needs for your question to be accepted.

Comment: This is what I expected. I will go through 'Theodicy' first and if I need further clarification, I will let the users of Philosophy to know if my question is On Topic their.

Comment: @SathiyaKumar I don't know how active their chat room is, but that might be a good place to get help refining your question.  Good luck.